# Android rating baar not showing properly

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

`Ratingbar` star not showing properly.
i don't know what i am doing wrong with it.
when i used custom style then a single star is showing only and its length is equal to 5star.

```
<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
android:stepSize="1"
android:numStars="5"
style="@style/customRatingBar" />
```

Style is:

```
<style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/manual_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">32dip</item>
</style>
```

manual_ratingbar file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_unselect" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_select" />
</layer-list>
```

it looks like: 
[image]

and when i changed the Ratingbar style to

```
style="?attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
```

then there is extra star visible in background.
[image]
 what should i do?

Comment: remove `<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_unselect" />` in manual_ratingbar

Comment: still looking like first screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chandan you can resolve this issue by adding this on RatingBar Layout `android:indeterminate="false"`